# sendmsg() and recvmsg() system calls

Tags: c, sockets

I have been working on socket programming and I have encountered a problem. I am using sendmsg and recvmsg system calls to send messages to server from client and print it at server. I am using the UDP protocol. However its throwing the error: Invalid argument.

Client

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Usage: client <serverpno> <serverip>");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int sock;
    char buffer[512];
    char rev_buffer[512];
    int address_length,message_length;
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    
    //making a socket
    sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if (sock<0){
        perror("error in socket making in client.c");
        exit(1);
    
    }

    //defining the client
    client.sin_family=AF_INET;
    client.sin_port=htons(0);
    client.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(0L);

    //binding socket to client
    if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client,sizeof(client))<0){
        perror("binding error in client to sock");
        exit(1);
    }

    //defining the server
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[2]);

    //getting input for the message to send
    printf("enter the message to send to server: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    int c=read(0,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    if (c<0){
        perror("reading error");
        exit(1);
    }

    //sending to server
    struct iovec i;
    i.iov_base=buffer;
    i.iov_len=sizeof(buffer);

    struct msghdr msg;
    memset(&msg,0,sizeof(msg));
    msg.msg_name=(caddr_t)argv[2];
    msg.msg_namelen=sizeof(inet_addr(argv[2]));
    msg.msg_iovlen=1;
    msg.msg_iov=&i;
    message_length=sendmsg(sock,&msg,0);
    if (message_length<0){
        perror("error in sending message to server");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Server

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    if (argc!=2){
        printf("Usage server <serverpno>");
        exit(1);
    }

    int sockmain,i;
    char buffer[512];
    char rev_buffer[512];
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    int address_length,message_length,reverse_length;

    sockmain=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if (sockmain<0){
        perror("server socket creation error");
        exit(1);
    }

    //setting up server socket
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1])); 
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(0L); 
    
    //binding server socket 
    if (bind(sockmain,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server))<0){
        perror("binding at server issue");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    //receiving from client
    struct iovec iv;
    iv.iov_base=buffer;
    iv.iov_len=sizeof(buffer);

    struct msghdr msg;
    msg.msg_name=NULL;
    msg.msg_namelen=sizeof(client);
    memset(&msg,0,sizeof(msg));
    msg.msg_iovlen=1;
    msg.msg_iov=&iv;
    message_length=recvmsg(sockmain,&msg,0);
    if (message_length<0){
        perror("receive from error in server.c\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `msg.msg_name=(caddr_t)argv[2]; msg.msg_namelen=sizeof(inet_addr(argv[2]));` this doesn't look right.

Comment: can you please tell what is the right way? I want the msg_name to point to my current machine's address . so I am giving argv[2] as 0.0.0.0. But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You must give the length of string not size of inet_addr

Comment: Your `argv[2]` is a string, `inet_addr` returns an `in_addr_t`. Neither of those are what you need. You need a pointer to `sockaddr_in` and `sizeof(sockarrd_in)` (or `sockaddr_in6` if you use ipv6).

Comment: `msg.msg_name=NULL; msg.msg_namelen=sizeof(client);` is not correct either. You need either `NULL` and `0`, or a pointer to a buffer and a size of that buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working properly now.